# How to get average by cell content on VBA

Tags: vba, excel

In excel, I have column 1 with tickers, and column 2 with numbers, like this:

```
      A  B    
1    AAA 10
2    AAA 12
3    AAA 14
4    BBB  9
5    BBB 10
6    BBB 11
```

I need a piece of code to calculate average BY TICKER, which means that in this case I would have AAA average : 12 and BBB average = 10, etc etc etc. Up to now all i got is this code which tries to calculate the sums, I will do the divisions later, but something's wrong:

```
For row = 2 to 6
Ticker = Cells(row - 1, 1)
If Cells(row, 1) = Cells(row - 1, 1) Then
sum = sum + Cells(row, 2)
Else
Cells(row, 6) = sum
sum = 0
row = row + 1
Next
```

I get an error saying "For is missing"

Comment: I think you are missing an `end if`.

Comment: Have you looked at the spreadsheet formula `AVERAGEIF`? I think that can do what you need without VBA.

Comment: See the [AVERAGEIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIF-function-ff3c70f9-5afe-4d3e-87d4-717187f98c20)  and [AVERAGEIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-48910C45-1FC0-4389-A028-F7C5C3001690)  functions.

Comment: Yes, but I have 100 tickers. I don't want to write 100 times: average if ticker=AAA etc etc etc, do you agree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe something like this in C1.

```
=IF(A1<>A2,AVERAGEIF(A:A,A1,B:B),"")
```

[image: averageif_once]

Comment: I like the use of `A1<>A2`. I assumed (like you) that the raw data is ordered.

Comment: Well, we can only go on what the OP offers as example and the sample data was ordered. Very often sample data is redacted and simplified to the point where a viable solution will never work on actual data but you have to start somewhere.

Comment: even if not ordered, to keep the way your example looks, you could use in C1 `=AVERAGEIF(A:A,A1,B:B)` and in C2 `=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A1,A2),"",AVERAGEIF(A:A,A2,B:B))` which can be copied down from C2 and is not an array formula ;)

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

- sum ignored the first AAA
- missed the End If
- incremented row twice, once by row = row+1 and then by next
- and some other not used variables

Try this:

```
Prev = "***"
For row = 1 to 6
  If Cells(row, 1) = prev Then
    sum = sum + Cells(row, 2)
  Else
    Cells(row, 6) = sum
    sum = 0
  End If
  prev = Cells(row,1)
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

To extend the answer from Jeeped and do it with a list which is not ordered, you also could do it like this:

```
C1:       =A1
C2:       =IF(LEN(C1),IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1,(COUNTIF(C$1:C1,A$1:A$1000)=0)*(A$1:A$1000<>""),0)),""),"")}
C3....Cn: copy down from C2

D1:      =IF(LEN(C1),AVERAGEIF(A:A,C1,B:B),"")
D2...Dn: copy down from D1
```

C2 is an array formula and needs to be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

to do it via VBA (should be faster than my formula for really big tables) you can use something like that: (put this in a "Module" in the VBA-Window, the same like your recorded macros ar written)

```
Option Explicit

Public Function getAllAvg(rng As Range) As Variant
  Set rng = Intersect(rng.Parent.UsedRange, rng)

  Dim varInput As Variant
  varInput = rng.Value

  Dim varOutput() As Variant
  ReDim varOutput(1 To UBound(varInput), 1 To 2)
  varOutput(1, 1) = ""

  Dim i As Long, j As Long
  For i = 1 To UBound(varInput)
    If Len(varInput(i, 1)) Then
      j = 1

      While Len(varOutput(j, 1)) And (varOutput(j, 1) <> varInput(i, 1)) And (j < UBound(varOutput))
        j = j + 1
      Wend

      If Len(varOutput(j, 1)) = 0 Then
        varOutput(j, 1) = varInput(i, 1)
        varOutput(j, 2) = Application.AverageIf(rng.Columns(1), varOutput(j, 1), rng.Columns(2))
        varOutput(j + 1, 1) = ""
      End If

    End If
  Next

  While Len(varOutput(j, 1)) And (j < UBound(varOutput))
  j = j + 1
  Wend

  If Len(varOutput(j, 1)) = 0 Then
    For i = j To UBound(varOutput)
      varOutput(i, 1) = ""
      varOutput(i, 2) = ""
    Next
  End If
  getAllAvg = varOutput
End Function
```

then select a range like C2:D12 and enter:

```
=getAllAvg(A:B)
```

and confirm with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>. it will directly output the whole list (and recalculate if needed)

**EDIT**:

If your list is always in a sorted order, you also could use this code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Function getAllAvgSorted(rng As Range) As Variant
  Set rng = Intersect(rng.Parent.UsedRange, rng)

  Dim varInput As Variant
  varInput = rng.Value

  Dim varOutput() As Variant
  ReDim varOutput(1 To UBound(varInput), 1 To 2)
  varOutput(1, 1) = ""

  Dim i As Long, j As Long
  j = 1

  For i = 1 To UBound(varInput)
    If Len(varInput(i, 1)) Then
      If varOutput(j, 1) <> varInput(i, 1) Then
        If Len(varOutput(j, 1)) Then j = j + 1
        varOutput(j, 1) = varInput(i, 1)
        varOutput(j, 2) = Application.AverageIf(rng.Columns(1), varOutput(j, 1), rng.Columns(2))
      End If
    End If
  Next

  While j < UBound(varOutput)
    j = j + 1
    varOutput(j, 1) = ""
    varOutput(j, 2) = ""
  Wend

  getAllAvgSorted = varOutput
End Function
```